# deploy localhost:3000 file. But after deploy to myapp.meteor.com, get empty page.

Tags: meteor, deployment

I have deployed my first app to meteor.com. It is called evideo.meteor.com.
I gets empty page. But when deploying to my local machine deployment, it was fine.

It is an app that can load or take pictures/videos.

Comment: Make sure you don't have duplicate "atError" template. This error is popping first.

Answer (score 0):

I enter your app website and open the console, finding that there are some errors. You might check it out.